# An uncountable set $X$ doesn't have a countable base under cofinite topology.

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be an infinite set and $T= \left\lbrace V \subset X : V = \emptyset \text{ or } X \backslash V \text{ is a finite set }\right\rbrace$. Let $X$ be an uncountable set. Prove that $X$ doesn't have a countable base.

I'm trying to prove that by pointing out the contradiction which is "$X$ has a countable base" is wrong, but I didn't manage the proof. Can you show me the way to prove this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume $X$ has a countable base $\mathcal B=\{U_1,U_2,\ldots\}$.  Put $V_n=X\setminus U_n$.  Show that if $U$ is open in $X$, then $X\setminus U\subset\cup_n V_n$.  But $\cup_n V_n$ is at most countably infinite, so if $X$ were uncountable we could find some $U\subset X$ open with $X\setminus U$ not a subset of $\cup_n V_n$, a contradiction.

Comment: What is your definition of U?

Comment: $U$ is just some open set.